# How to delete Elementary OS without another OS installation?

Tags: release-loki, system-installation

It is my last week at my current workplace. I use Elementary OS on my working PC where I have a lot of personal information. I want to fully erase OS from this PC without installation of any another OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved in this way:

1. Create a new user with admin permissions and log in.
2. Remove your user in settings.
3. Remove your user directory from `home` directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to delete everything you can achieve this by an eOS USB flash drive. Just boot your computer from the usb flash drive, choose 'Try elementary OS without installing' and use GParted application to format the drive you want to clear.

Comment: Good answer, but I solved this in another way.

Comment: Yes as long as it works for you it is ok. But the question you asked was to delete everything, not only the personal data, so that is why I suggested to you to do that.